# Display recently playing videos from a website to my Android app

Tags: android, json, api, video-streaming

I want to display the recently playing videos from a video streaming websites in a LinearLayout in my Android app. I know how to make an activity have a linear layout to put the videos to but I don't know how to get those videos from that website. Would I need JSON parsing to do it? Does anyone have any information about how to display recently playing videos on a video streaming website to an Android app (any links to useful stuff like API's etc) ? I tried Google but didn't get something useful.

Comment: What have you tried? Does the video website have a JSON interface or do you need to do scraping yourself?

Comment: No the website doesn't have any JSON interface. And I've just tried Googling but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

If the website doesn't have a JSON interface (or any other). Then you should do scraping.
This involves downloading the HTML (via e.g. HttpClient), parsing the HTML and search for the video URLs.

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer by giving any links etc?